# Can I publish 2 sites using separate app bundles in the same beanstalk env?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a the following app bundles that use Beanstalk [Custom deployments](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/deployment-beanstalk-custom.html):

app_bundleA

```
- SiteA
- aws-windows-deployment-manifest.json
- installSiteA.ps1
- uninstallSiteA.ps1
- restart.ps1
```

app_bundleB

```
- SiteB
- aws-windows-deployment-manifest.json
- installSiteB.ps1
- uninstallSiteB.ps1
- restart.ps1
```

app_bundleA installSiteA.ps1 (showing only ps1 scripts for bundleA as it is similar to B):

```
# install the SiteA site
Copy-Item -Path "C:\staging\SiteA" -Destination "C:\inetpub" -Recurse -Force

$manager = Get-IISServerManager
$site = $manager.Sites.Add("SiteA", "http", "*:80:", "C:\inetpub\SiteA")
$manager.CommitChanges()
```

app_bundleA uninstallSiteA.ps1:

```
Remove-IISSite -Name "Intranet" -Confirm:$False
rm -r "c:\inetpub\intranet" -Force
```

app_bundleA restart.ps1:

```
iisreset /timeout:1
```

app_bundleA aws-windows-deployment-manifest (app_bundleB is similar):

```
{
  "manifestVersion": 1,
  "deployments": {
    "custom": [
      {
        "name": "SiteA",
        "scripts": {
          "install": {
            "file": "instalSiteA.ps1"
          },
          "restart": {
            "file": "restart.ps1"
          },
          "uninstall": {
            "file": "uninstalSiteA.ps1"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

When I upload `app_bundleA` to beanstalk (using the AWS Console) it goes and deploys the `SiteA` fine. However, when I deploy `app_bundleB` after that, it will uninstall `SiteA` and leave just `SiteB` deployed.

My goal is to have both `SiteA` & `SiteB` deployed but using 2 separate app bundles. The reason is that we have those sites in 2 separate git repos having separate CI pipelines.

I don't understand why Beanstalk uninstalls my previously deployed `SiteA` when I deploy `SiteB`.

Is the above even possible to achieve using Beanstalk?

Comment: It is possible, but it would require a lot of customization. It could be just easier to run them on regular EC2 instances or ECS containers.

Comment: Thanks. So I am correct to think that beanstalk does uninstall all existing sites before installing new ones by design? I could not find anything on their documentation about that. Also, I am thinking to use ECS Fargate

Comment: It  will delete existing one, thus you would have to do a lot of customization and "hacks" to make it work. Either use two different EBs, or containers on Fargate. It will be easier than to hack up such a solution on a single EB.

Comment: Thank you @Marcin. I will go ahead and move away from Beanstalk as you suggested. It will become a big hack and the whole point of using that service is to make my life easier but it won't from the looks of it in my usecase. Thank you again :)